# Create a dynamic range with the same row

Tags: excel

I have a list of prices (closing price of a stock) and I would like a formula in another column that returns the value of the closing price except if a value has been reached before the last value.
[image]

Imagine that when the stock price fixes at a price higher than 17, the column returns NA().

I used the formula =IF(H2>17;NA();H2) until the last row (252 fixings), but I would like to refer to the range from the first cell (H2) to the last cell (H:Row()).

How can I do that ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood properly. Could you post the expected output?

Comment: looking for [ `=IF(max(H$2:H2)>17;NA();H2)` (put formula in H2, drag downwards) ] ... ?